# Why does Unity launcher start the wrong program?

Tags: libreoffice

When I left click the *LibreOffice* Icon *firefox* launches instead.  A Right click gives me a choice of

- New Document
- Firefox
- Lock to Launcher.

Until some recent updates this never happened before. Other programs don't exhibit this behaviour.  Why?

Comment: Though this is not a direct solution, what happens if you unlock it from `launcher` and then add it again by dragging it from `dash`?